# Citrix not connecting in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, connection, citrix

Cannot connect to. Address family not supported by protocol. Verify your connection settings and try again.

EVerything was working fine. Suddenly, I am getting this error. I deleted the softlink for certificates and recreated. Still not working.

Comment: Any update on this ? I have to make this one work in ubuntu 20.04

Comment: can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Somebody, please help me.

Comment: Please help me. I did not get even a single reply for this issue.

Comment: Struggling for a while now no response from citrix either... What a shame.

Comment: doogle
This issue for resolved. If you are trying to connect from mobile hot spot, disable ipv6. Try connecting only through ipv4.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what a bummer. Phew got it fixed now. Never thought of it till now.

Answer (score 4):

After fighting for long with this issue, found some link where its mentioned to try disabling ipv6 and it should work.
referred this link to disable ipv6
https://itsfoss.com/disable-ipv6-ubuntu-linux/

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

though there is mechanism mentioned to do disable ipv6 permanently  I preferred to create is a command which i will execute only when i want to connect to citrix.
working smoothly for me (with ubuntu 20.04, citrix workspace).

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!